# Conditional Import of 2 objets with the same name

Tags: javascript, import

How can I import 2 objects with the same name but conditionally use them on the page

I tried this, but import can be only on top so it doesn't work

```
if (window.location.href.includes('showcase')) {
  import { Tags } from "../../../data/folder1";
} else {
  import { Tags } from "../../../data/folder2";
}
```

I tried also this but I'm stuck:

```
 import { Tags } from "../../../data/folder1"
 import { Tags } from "../../../data/folder2"

const PageTags = window.location.href.includes('showcase') ? Tags : Tags <=== issue here
```

Comment: [Dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) - ps: probably best used alongside top-level-await.

Comment: There has to be a good original for this...

Comment: E.g.: ```const { Tags } = await import(`../../../data/${window.location.href.includes('showcase') ? "folder1" : "folder2"}`);``` Note that some bundlers may not support entirely dynamic imports like this, though modern browders do.

Comment: Re your attempt at the end, if you're really okay with importing them both and then only using one, you could use import renaming: `import { Tags as Tags1 } from "../../data/folder1"; import { Tags as Tags2 } from "../../data/folder2"; const Tags = window.location.href.includes("showcase") ? Tags1 : Tags2;`

Comment: Amazing, thank you @T.J.Crowder

Comment: FWIW, I cover renaming (and dynamic import) in my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* (Chapter 13). Links in my profile if you're interested. Happy coding!